# lwip waiting for new client how do I test

Tags: lwip

I got lwip to run on my embedded processor.  It prints out a series of debug messages-

```
[ethernet] PHY INFO: Interface: 0 Waiting for PHY
[ethernet] PHY INFO: [PHY ID] 0x0 141 dd1
[ethernet] PHY INFO: Issuing PHY Reset
[ethernet] PHY INFO: Waiting on PHY link...
[ethernet] PHY INFO: PHY link detected, allowing network to start.
Starting socket test interface
socket returns 32
Binding socket
Listening for socket
Waiting for new client
```

Then it stops - I want to do something to test it, something like ping.  I turned on the

```
#define LWIP_BROADCAST_PING             1
#define LWIP_MULTICAST_PING             1
```

I tried dhcp on and off.
I am using the ip address in->

```
int get_ip_addr(int iface, ip_addr_t* ipaddr, ip_addr_t* netmask, ip_addr_t* gw, int* use_dhcp)
{
    char buf[5];
    // set configuration
    IP4_ADDR(ipaddr, 192, 168, 0, 218);
    IP4_ADDR(netmask, 255, 255, 255, 0);
```

I do not see any connection made and the ping fails.  Lwip never moves on from waiting for new client.  I am using a dedicated port on my PC, I am monitoring traffic with wireshark.

I am not sure how to start a client or get a ping to work, any ideas are welcome.
Thanks,
Martin